# How to make @Lazy spring bean not eligible for creation when ListableBeanFactory#getBeansOfType is called with allowEagerInit = true?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-data-cassandra

I want to Spring Data Cassandra to be initialized lazily. To do it, I exclude some autoconfigurations and make CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean @Lazy, and it works. But when I enable rabbit, some code from spring amqp calls ListableBeanFactory#getBeansOfType with allowEagerInit = true during startup, and it initializes Cassandra on startup.

So, how can I make @Lazy spring bean not eligible for creation when ListableBeanFactory#getBeansOfType is called with allowEagerInit = true?

Comment: Just make initialization process (of Cassandra, not bean) on demand and don't trust lazy initialization

Comment: I opened [an issue against Spring AMQP](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/885) to fix this.